# Deploy mysql .jar with GlassFish 3

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, glassfish-3

I want to develop a db application and I download latest mysql JDBC driver and
when I put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar` into glassfish_inst_dir/lib or
into my WEB-INF/lib I have always this error:

**No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users"**

Here my jsp code:

```
<sql:setDataSource url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  user="us" password="pw" var="ds"/>

<sql:query var="users" dataSource="${ds}" >
SELECT * FROM users</sql:query>
```

What's the error?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not fimilar with glassfish but I think you have to create a datasource in the console. But first thing, check that this driver is compatible with your mysql version.

Answer (score 5):

The [docs for GlassFish Server 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html#ghatb) say that the JDBC driver should be copied into your domain's lib dir and the server should be restarted after you do this.

The domain's lib directory is (typically) glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib, if you are using the domain1 that is part of the standard install.  If you are on Windows, your domain's lib directory may be %HOME%/.netbeans/%NBVER%/GF3/domain1.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work! I have also found this strange behaviours. First if I deploy a servlet with Java code it works!!! Then if I undeploy the .jar from lib the servlet again works!!!

Comment: Ok I found the answer. The .jar must be deployed into lib/etx dir. Strange because the server doc say it must be into the lib!!!

Comment: Thanks to "xdevel2000". Just to reiterate, the Database drivers must be copied within the: **<your_domain>/lib/ext** folder, NOT just /lib folder. This worked for me too. This is true in all Glassfish versions.

Comment: why should the database driver go in <domain>/lib/ext and **not** /lib?  documentation wrong, or is there something more subtle here?